# Need clarification on VHDL expressions involving std_logic_vector, unsigned and literals, unsure about compiler interpretation

Tags: math, types, vhdl, unsigned, ieee

I do not understand how the following operations `2s – 1` and `1 - 2s` are performed in the following expressions:

```vhdl
R <= (s & '0') - 1;

L <= 1-(s & '0');
```

Considering the fact that `R` and `L` are of type `signed(1 downto 0)` and `s` of type `std_logic`. I have extracted them from a `vhdl` code snippet in my professor's notes.

**What I understand (or at least consider to understand – premises of my reasoning)**

1. The concatenation with the `0` literal achieves the product by `2` (That is what shifting to the left does).
2. The concatenation also achieves a `std_logic_vector` of 2 bits (not so sure about that, I inferred this from a comment in the following [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689477/how-to-add-std-logic-using-numeric-std)
3. "`std_logic_vector` is great for implementing data buses, it’s useless for performing arithmetic operations" - source: [vhdlwhiz](https://vhdlwhiz.com/signed-unsigned/#:%7E:text=Finally%2C%20signed%20and%20unsigned%20can,can%20only%20have%20number%20values).

**What baffles me:**

1. What type does the compiler interpret the `1` literal is?

   - An integer? If so, can an `integer` be used without casting in an arithmetic expression with a `std_logic_vector`? This option doesn't seem very plausible to me...
   - Assuming the fact that the `(s & '0')` is indeed interpreted as a `std_logic_vector` (second premise) it also comes to my mind the possibility that the compiler, based on the type of the other operand in the expression (i.e., `(s & '0')`), inferred `1` to be of type `std_logic_vector` as well. However, even though both `(s & '0')`  and `1` were interpreted as `std_logic_vector` they should not be behaving correctly according to my third premise.

     - A thought that comes to my mind in order tu justify the possibility of both operands being of type `std_logic_vector` is that both `(s & '0')`  and `1` are implicitly casted to `signed` by the compiler because it acknowledges the fact the signal in which the result is stored is of type `signed`. This, doesn't seem to make sense to me (suppose `s` is equal to `1`):
       `R <= (s & '0') - 1;`

       Both operands are converted to `std_logic_vectors(1 downto 0)`
       `R <= "10" - "01"`

       Now, if the contents of the std_logic_vectors were interpreted as `signed` the result of the subtraction would be
       `R <= (-2) - (1) = -3`

As you can tell I am really confused. I believe we've only scratched the surface when it comes to discussing data types in class and I am encountering a lot of problems when solving problems because choosing the wrong data types.

I apologize for any lack of clarity in my questions; they reflect my current understanding of the subject. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance in the conext provided, (s & '0') does not create a std_logic_vector, it creates a `signed`. VHDL is a context driven language. Because no arithmatic is available on `std_logic_vector`, and the types of `L` and `R` are signed, the arithemtic must be of the signature (from ieee.numeric_std):

```vhdl
function "-" (L: NATURAL; R: SIGNED) return SIGNED;
function "-" (L: SIGNED;  R: NATURAL) return SIGNED;
```

The numeric_std package provides the arithmetic functions above between signed and integer types, hence the `1` value is converted inside the `"-"` function to be the same as the other operand, in this case, a `signed` of 2 bits.